# Get the date of sunday of the current week in IOs

Tags: ios, nsdate, nscalendar, nsdatecomponents

I have searched for the solution to find the date of the sunday of the particular week.I have found questions that have been answered but it doesnt show the correct date of sunday.

```
NSCalendar *calendar = [NSCalendar currentCalendar];
unsigned unitFlags = NSCalendarUnitYear | NSCalendarUnitMonth |  NSCalendarUnitDay | NSCalendarUnitHour | NSCalendarUnitMinute | NSCalendarUnitWeekday | NSCalendarUnitWeekOfYear;
NSDateComponents *comps = [calendar components:unitFlags fromDate:[NSDate date]];
comps.weekday = 1;  //Sunday
comps.weekOfMonth = 1;
NSDate *sundayDate = [calendar dateFromComponents:comps];
```

When i print out the date it gives this.

```
2015-07-08 10:14:00 +0000
```

Its the current date.What am i doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

hope this helps you :

```
    NSDate *today = [NSDate date];
    NSCalendar *calenderObj = [[NSCalendar alloc] initWithCalendarIdentifier:NSGregorianCalendar];
    calenderObj.firstWeekday = 1; // Sunday = 1, 
     // NSDateComponents *components = [calenderObj components:NSWeekOfYearCalendarUnit fromDate:today];
    NSDate *objDate = nil;
 [calenderObj rangeOfUnit:NSWeekCalendarUnit startDate:&objDate interval:NULL forDate:today];
    NSLog(@" === %@",  objDate);
```

Output :

**=== 2015-07-15 10:26:00 +0000**

Comment: You're not using the `components` object for anything.

Comment: @mattsson yes not using components, as required console for above question is already available in calenderObj ...